# How to create specific response for each item in Listview

Tags: android, listview

here's my code of customized Listview ,,

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Simple array with a list of my favorite TV shows
        String[] Teams = {"RealMadrid", "Barcelona", "Juventus", "BayernMunich"};

        ListAdapter theAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row_layout, R.id.textView1, favoriteTVShows);
        theListView.setAdapter(theAdapter);

        ...
    }
}
```

my click listener here :

```
theListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
        String tvShowPicked = "You selected " + String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, tvShowPicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

as you can see I have common response for all the items of the list , what if I want to set a specific response to each item for example when I click on first item it opens a website ,, & the second item opens different website & so on

Comment: Why not use switch statement? switch(i)

Comment: Used your specific Object with type and check this type in your listener to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of more elegant ways to do this, but to get you on the right track you can go with a switch/case.

```
theListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

        switch(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i))
        {
            case 0:
            // open a webview
            break;
            case 1:
            // do something else
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to make this a little more robust, your objects for the listview can have types set, such as 'website', or 'dialog box', or 'intent', or 'fragment' etc. Then instead you would check what the type is and based on the type do something. Of course there are many other solutions to your problem but I think this is the easiest answer for me to give, given the information you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

The argument position will have the row number of clicked item from the list :

If Position = 0 -> open yahoo.com
If Position = 1 -> open google.com

Better yet use switch wiith position in argument.